# Como lidar com uma pergunta que depende de um conhecimento além da programação?

Tags: debate, escopo-do-site

Tenho respondido algumas perguntas de [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) no SOpt, e vejo que muitas perguntas acabam sendo fechadas por não serem claras o suficiente.

Como o R é uma linguagem voltada a estatística/análise de dados, muito de seus usuários (inclusive eu) não são programadores profissionais. Além disso, como estatística é um assunto que está na moda, muitos usuários de R além de não serem programadores, não são estatísticos.

Por isso, acredito que muitas vezes as pessoas confundem um erro, que na verdade, é um problema na forma com que estão usando estatística, com um erro de programação em [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) e perguntam aqui no site.

### Minha pergunta é:

Quando esse tipo de pergunta aparece, devemos esclarecer o usuário do site, que essa não é uma pergunta de programação, e que portanto não deve estar no site?
Ou devemos deixá-la aberta até que alguém capacitado consiga responder?

#### Perguntas deste tipo:

- [GLMER, dados longitudinais, fator aleatorio, Binomial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135002/6036)
- [Influence.measures usando o LOESS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125183/6036)
- [GLM, Poisson - números de contagem não inteiros (média)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81924/6036)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135700/6036

Comment: Nao precisa ser programador profissional pra programar e existem muitas perguntas em outras linguagens que vão alem da programação. O algorítimo talvez defina isto, se o problema 'e o algorítimo então a pergunta esta dentro do escopo sim.

Comment: clar que não precisa, desculpe se deixei a entender isso. meu ponto é que muitas vezes as pessoas estão usando o algoritmo corretamente (da forma da programação), mas não o algoritmo correto do ponto de vista estatístico, e por isso algumas perguntas de R estão sendo suspensas

Comment: Se o algoritimo nao faz o que 'e porque a pessoa veio procurar ajuda para corrigi-lo, ou seja nao tem como usar o algoritimo de forma correta se ele nao faz o esperado. Nao existe algoritimo pra programacao e algoritimo pra estatisticas, o que existem sao algoritimos e se eles nao funcionam como esperado 'e porque existe alguma falha.

Comment: Sim, estou só listando... Acho melhor assim mesmo!

Comment: Como não? São perguntas de estatística que envolvem quase nada de programação que apareceram aqui no site.

Comment: Essa que eu votei para fechar, por exemplo: Para responder seria necessário dar uma aula de [modelos mistos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model), que é um assunto denso de estatística e não depende em nenhum momento de programação.

Comment: Daniel eu entendi, acho que foi o que eu já disse na resposta, se for algo que não pode ser reproduzido ou amplo demais deve ser fechado, isso será valido pra qualquer linguagem, se o autor da pergunta tiver um problema no algorítimo então é on-topic, desde que possa reproduzir o código (qualquer linguagem).

Comment: Certo. O problema é que esse limite pode ser tênue, você não acha? Por isso coloquei exemplos na minha pergunta. Pensei bastante antes de votar para fechar a `GLMER, dados longitudinais, fator aleatorio, Binomial`, p/ mim esta é uma que se encaixa nas off-topic, mas as outras que estão lá p/ mim são do mesmo estilo, mas são on-topic, outras pessoas podem pensar diferente... Por isso acho importante a discussão.

Comment: Daniel eu concordo contigo, em nenhum momento discordei depois que eu disse `eu entendi` no comentário anterior. O que estou explicando é o como você pode classificar do seu ponto de vista o que é on-topic e o que é off-topic e o que é simplesmente amplo-demais (diferente de off-topic) e o que não está claro, vou tentar adicionar na resposta de uma maneira pratica.

Comment: Tá ok editei a resposta, mas vou editar um pouco mais provavelmente, só preciso conversar com o pessoal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perguntas que tratam somente de estatística mas não de programação devem ser fechadas e direcionadas para o [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (que infelizmente ainda não temos em português). O caso da pergunta [associaçao entre variaveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58964/associa%C3%A7ao-entre-variaveis) é claramente este, essa pergunta não envolve nada de programação.

Perguntas que envolvam elementos de programação e estatística ao mesmo tempo têm que ser editadas (quando possível) para darem ênfase na parte da dúvida que diz respeito à programação.

Às vezes os problemas que os usuários têm com a parte da estatística acabam levando a dúvidas sobre programação (por exemplo, o usuário tem dúvidas sobre argumentos de uma certa função). Neste caso, não vejo problema de a resposta esclarecer pontos de estatística para explicar por que a parte de programação está errada, desde que seja algo auxiliar.

Comment: [essa pergunta sobre regressão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81924/glm-poisson-n%C3%BAmeros-de-contagem-n%C3%A3o-inteiros-m%C3%A9dia) é um claro problema de estatística que acarretou em um problema de programação. Eu acredito que devemos ser um pouco mais abrangentes em casos como este, pois aparecem muitas perguntas e respostas interessantes também!

Comment: @DanielFalbel para mim essa pergunta entra no segundo ponto, de estatística com programação, que deve ter o foco na parte da programação. Ela não estava entendendo a mensagem de warning e queria saber o que estava acontecendo. Uma resposta focando em explicar a mensagem e com um exemplo acho suficiente. Mas a linha realmente pode ser tênue, se começasse uma discussão maior sobre teoria e GLM aí caberia fechamento, pois fugiria demais do escopo.

Answer (score 23):

Olha posso estar enganado, mas o escopo do site aceita perguntas que sejam ou dependam de um algorítimo, até algumas questões de matemática (foram exceções) foram aceitas, então se a pergunta for depender da linguagem e de um algorítimo então me parece sim on-topic, situações que vejo como off-topic ou precisam ser fechadas seriam:

- Pedido para fazer algo por ele
- Perguntas que não tem como ser reproduzidas ou estão amplas demais

Note que muitas perguntas em diversas linguagens já feitas aqui no site dependem de algum conhecimento além da programação, mas ainda sim o que importa era que o processo na maioria das vezes foi resolvido no algorítimo ou codificação, e claro também que tem **raras exceções** que ainda podem ser consideradas on-topic para o site mesmo que não seja algo resolvido na codificação, veja este exemplo de exceção [acesso externo com wamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50927/3635) (é uma situação "rara" como eu disse, não quer dizer que todas sejam on-topic)

**Eu** faria assim para determinar a situação de uma pergunta:

- Se está confusa, não da pra ter certeza o que perguntou, vote para fechar como `Não está clara`
- Se é algo que pode ser resolvido no algorítimo, mas depende de fatores externos e não pode ser reproduzido, vote como `ampla demais` (não tenho certeza, vou conversas com o pessoal mais experiente e editar depois)
- Se é algo que não depende em nada do algorítimo, vote como "fora do escopo" na opção `não é sobre programação`
- Se é algo que pode reproduzir dentro do que é especificado no link [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e o problema pode ser resolvido de maneira simples ou no código então pode manter em aberta

### sobre as perguntas citadas/linkdas

Elas não foram suspensas por se tratar de [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) ou por depender de algo a mais, se você observar o rodapé das perguntas fechadas ou suspensas vai notar o motivo escrito  do porque disto, como por exemplo:

1. [Como rodar uma regressão linear no R oy Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81281/3635)

   - Fechada porque não está clara
2. [Utilizando o código abaixo, porque eu só estou coletando os dados da última página do Loop?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80016/3635)

   - Fechada porque não está clara
3. [Como fazer uma MLP no R cuja saída seja a posteriori e o conjunto de teste classificado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/69916/3635)

   - Fechada porque não está clara
4. [associação entre variáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58964/3635)

   - Fechada porque e uma *duplicata*

A única pergunta que achei fechada no sentido que você disse foi esta:

- [Associação entre variáveis: base de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58894/3635)

  Lendo, me parece sim uma pergunta sobre o uso do [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), no entanto eu não entendo desta linguagem e não consigo ter certeza, suponho que se for algo que realmente seja o uso da linguagem então você pode votar pra reabri-la.

### Detalhes:

Se pesquisar assim, vai notar que só tem *5 perguntas* fechadas em [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r):

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+closed%3Ayes

Se pesquisar assim, irá mostrar que tem 213 (até o momento) perguntas abertas:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+closed%3Ano

### Conclusão

- Acredito que todas perguntas fechadas são apenas porque os autores não conseguiram expressar o problema, o que não é a dificuldade apenas dos que não são *programadores profissionais*, mas de qualquer um, o problema de comunicação e expressão existe em qualquer área.
- **Note** que uma pergunta fechada não quer dizer *BANIDA* ou *DELETADA PARA TODO O SEMPRE*, fechar uma pergunta serve apenas para evitar que ela receba respostas sem seguir o padrão de qualidade mínimo da comunidade.
- **Note também** que uma pergunta pode sim ser fechada por engano, errar é humano, desde que possa ser reaberta.
- Todas perguntas podem ser reabertas, até as duplicatas, basta o autor editar e justificar o motivo. Apenas por editá-la, a pergunta já entra em uma fila de análise e usuários com 3000 ou mais pontos podem votar pra reabri-la e se receber 5 votos ela será reaberta. Claro que a edição deve melhorar a pergunta, se a edição for insignificante para a melhoria da pergunta, então ninguém vai votar pra reabrir provavelmente.
- Não precisa ser **programador profissional** para programar ou perguntar aqui. Existem muitas perguntas em outras linguagens que vão além da programação aqui no StackOverflow em Português. Se a resposta ou pergunta dependem de um algoritmo escrito na tal linguagem, então a pergunta está dentro do escopo sim.

Comment: A pergunta "Associação entre variáveis: base de dados" é totalmente fora de escopo, e mal formulada. Não tem relação direta com programação, o AP queria ajudar sobre a melhor abordagem para analisar seus dados. Como se isso não bastasse, os dados não condizem com a descrição dada. O AP reconheceu isso nos comentários mas não fez nada para clarificar a pergunta.

Comment: Obs.: Até mesmo perguntas sobre algorítimos (sem uma linguagem específica) geralmente são aceitas.

Answer (score 11):

Completando a resposta do Guilherme, algumas dicas:

- Se você entendeu o que foi perguntado e acha que os outros não entenderam, você mesmo pode tentar clarificar a questão editando-a.
- Se não quer editar ou não concordou com o fechamento, faça uma pergunta aqui no meta especificamente sobre isso, explicando suas razões. Assim você pode chamar a atenção para algo que passou despercebido para os outros.
- Se realmente acha que faltou algum detalhe, mas a pergunta tem potencial, adicione um comentário pedindo ao AP (Autor da Pergunta) para adicionar a informação.

Enfim, este é um site colaborativo e aberto. Se há algo que você não concorda ou acha que está errado, não fique apenas esperando os outros agirem ou apenas aceite quieto, faça algo e leve o assunto para discussão.

Comment: Seu último parágrafo é *perfeita e totalmente* aplicável à política local.