# Reabrir uma pergunta sobre uma plataforma de desenvolvimento Xtech

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, razões-fechamento

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101126/xtech-formul%C3%A1rio-de-e-mail

Olá queria queria discutir sobre esta pergunta, não é uma pergunta muito simples. Porém não significa que está mal explicado (A pessoa tem que saber o que é Xtech, senão, não tem como opinar nem mesmo votar em algo que não sabe o que é).

A questão é que precisa de uma biblioteca padrão do sistema que não tem no meu template e eu queria que me ajudassem a descobrir qual é esta biblioteca.

Obrigado

Pessoal, descobri o problema que estava acontecendo... Não era uma biblioteca Javascript que estava faltando e sim um uma tag HTML que com ajuda do twig consegui fazer funcionar.

```
{# ------ #}
 {# ALERTS #}
 {# ------ #}
 <section id="flash">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     {% if flashdata.error %}
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
      {{ flashdata.error }}
      <a class="close-alert">{{'fechar'|trans({'en':'close'})}}</a>
     </div>
     {% endif %}
     {% if flashdata.message %}
     <div class="alert alert-info">
      {{ flashdata.message }}
      <a class="close-alert">{{'fechar'|trans({'en':'close'})}}</a>
     </div>
     {% endif %}
     {% if error %}
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
      {{ error }}
      <a class="close-alert">{{'fechar'|trans({'en':'close'})}}</a>
     </div>
     {% endif %}
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Agora acho que o pessoal que deu negativo e votou para fechar é por que não tentou interpretar direito e não quis ir atrás do problema, pois as perguntas respondidas aqui são mais claras como por exemplo: "Como faço a query X" ou como eu faço para acessar o banco de dados em Mysql em PHP.

Perguntas assim são fáceis dizer que foi clara e objetiva, agora quando se trata de um tecnologia nova, vocês tem que ir atrás ou nem responde...

Reli a pergunta e cheguei a conclusão o seguinte, a pergunta pode ser melhorada sim. Porém os dados que dei eram suficiente para achar a resolução do problema... E a maioria aqui nem tentou ajudar, apenas criticou a construção do texto falando que não foi clara o suficiente.

Um assunto complexo deve ter uma atenção redobrada e é claro que é muito mais difícil de entender.

Agora, por que vou ficar perdendo meu tempo editando a pergunta até os senhores gostarem se eu já achei a resposta? E isto de certa forma atrapalha a comunidade, pois alguém pode ter o mesmo problema mais para frente e não da para postar a resposta lá.

Ninguém pediu informações adicionais nos comentários, eu tive que abrir a discussão no meta para saber a causa do fechamento.

Comment: Duas opiniões: 1) Se a pessoa tem que saber que Xtech pra responder, acho que teria que no mínimo ter uma breve observação no corpo da pergunta dizendo o que é, ou mesmo na tag correspondente. 2) Legal você tratar do assunto aqui no meta, mas saiba que pra reabrir perguntas bastam 5 votos da comunidade, então naturalmente se a pergunta está adequada, a abertura acontece quase que sozinha.

Comment: Depende, as vezes a pergunta acaba sendo esquecida e a solução vem em uma velocidade mais rápida do que esperar reabrir a pergunta.

Levando em conta que não tenho todo tempo do mundo, apenas queria uma ajuda da comunidade pois desta vez está muito difícil achar uma solução.

Comment: ai que entra o ponto 1, nas próximas dúvidas ajudaria a evitar o fechamento, que também são 5 votos normalmente. Lembre-se que se você editar e melhorar a questão de alguma maneira, ela volta pra lista, e todo mundo vê. Geralmente essas melhorias que atraem votos de abertura (não especificamente falando desta questão, mas de qualquer uma)

Comment: A questão dos negativos é totalmente opinião de pessoais e pode ter sido por qualquer motivo, já os de fechar foram justificados e no rodapé da pergunta tem o motivo do fechamento e como eu disse na resposta aqui no meta, só porque esta claro pra ti não significa que esteja claro pra outras pessoas, quando estamos escrevendo ao invés de falar realmente ocorre estes problemas de dificuldade de se expressar. Ninguém votou pra fechar por maldade, entenda que fechar não é deletar ou banir uma pergunta, existem motivos bons para o fechamento - leia isto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635

Comment: Pra resumir, fechamento pode ou melhor deve ser considerado algo temporário pra resolver pendencias e seguir um padrão de qualidade da comunidade, não veja isto com "mals olhos", é apenas para manter a comunidade organizada, assim que a pergunta for "ajustada" ela poderá ser reaberta :)

Answer (score 9):

- > Perguntas assim são fáceis dizer que foi clara e objetiva, agora
  >   quando se trata de um tecnologia nova, vocês tem que ir atrás ou nem
  >   responde...

  Não tem haver com a tecnologia, o problema é que a pergunta esta de uma maneira escrita que não da para entender do que você esta falando, isto não é um problema que só você comete, todos nós costumamos ter dificuldade em nos expressar, então o problema todo é que você não conseguiu expressar a sua duvida de maneira que outras pessoas possam compreender, isto é normal e todos passamos por isto.
- > Um assunto complexo deve ter uma atenção redobrada e é claro que é muito mais difícil de entender.

  Vários membros aqui já se depararam com duvidas muito mais complexas em questão de tecnologia e conseguiram ajudar ou até mesmo dar uma incrível solução, já a sua pergunta não despertou o interesse de ninguém ajudar por causa da maneira que esta escrita, pois **"NINGUÉM"** que leu parece que conseguiu entender o que você quer exatamente, a dificuldade de entender nada tem nada haver com a tecnologia citada.
- > Agora, por que vou ficar perdendo meu tempo editando a pergunta até os senhores gostarem se eu já achei a resposta? E isto de certa forma atrapalha a comunidade, pois alguém pode ter o mesmo problema mais para frente e não da para postar a resposta lá.

  Desculpe mas isto é *muito desrespeitoso* e você não esta seguindo o minimo do que é sugerido no link [be-nice](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), vou lhe repetir novamente e espero realmente que entenda, ninguém quer que edite para que alguém aqui goste, então por favor preste atenção, os pedidos de edição foram de pessoas que querem te ajudar e pra isto é necessário entender o problema, que como já repeti, não da pra entender, então não leve a mal quem tenta lhe ajudar, sempre e sempre presuma boa intenção. Ninguém esta querendo perder o seu tempo, é justamente o contrário.
- > Ninguém pediu informações adicionais nos comentários, eu tive que abrir a discussão no meta para saber a causa do fechamento.

  Isto é muito importante, é legal comentar e explicar, mas é **totalmente opcional**, o próprio rodapé das perguntas pendentes e fechadas diz o motivo do fechamento, comentários com explicações são opcionais.

  E torno a repetir o quanto for necessário, **[fechar]** ou deixar **[pendente]** apenas é para evitar problemas e a pergunta pode e provavelmente será reaberta quando estiver dentro dos padrões mínimos da comunidade, Fechar não é deletar ou banir ou depreciar é apenas para controle e tem motivos, se quiser mais detalhes veja:

  - [Votos para fechar perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2676/3635)
  - [Campanha: Fechamento justo e explicado. Reabertura justa e explicada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/3635)

  Então entenda que as pessoas só estão tentando ajudar e torno a repetir:

  - presuma sempre boa intenção e seja respeitoso.

Agora se realmente quer reabrir a pergunta siga as dicas abaixo com atenção:

### Dicas para reabrir

O próprio site *Stack Overflow em Português* "sabe deste problema" e indica vários links para você encontrar a melhor maneira de se comunicar:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Seguindo as dicas destes links talvez consiga se expressar.

O principal problema da sua pergunta **não é por falta de código** ou porque ela é complexa, mas é porque não da pra entender o que exatamente funciona, na verdade a complexidade esta na maneira que escreveu e este *provavelmente* foi o problema que fez a sua pergunta ser fechada, afinal qual o problema exatamente?

Responda se é algum destes pontos:

- É o template?
- É o envio se é na hora de receber?
- É o css?
- É o html?
- Que biblioteca falha?
- Você pede ajuda pra descobrir qual é a "biblioteca", mas o sistema ao qual usa parece um CMS, sendo assim não tem muito sentido o termo biblioteca, a não ser que você tenha controle sobre o javascript ou css, é isso, um problema com css/js?
- Você fala de bootstrap, não da pra entender se a biblioteca que você quer descobrir é parte do boostrap ou não, o problema é com o bootstrap?

Viu quantas possibilidades de entendimento a sua pergunta gerou na cabeça, não da pra entender qual delas é ou se é outra coisa, se você conseguir expor o ponto exatamente que precisa saber, então pode ter certeza que as pessoas irão reabrir a pergunta.

### Quem votou

Note que não foi um moderador ou uma pessoa que decidiu fechar a sua pergunta, foram pessoas diferentes que votaram para isto e de opiniões diferentes e ninguém conversou entre si pra decidir apenas fechar a sua pergunta, cada voto de fechamento foi por um motivo pessoal, no entanto a maioria votou por fechar como "Não esta clara o suficiente" então entenda que nenhuma destas pessoas que votaram (5 pessoas diferentes) entenderam a pergunta, são 5 pessoas experientes e se 5 não entenderam então é porque esta difícil realmente de entender o problema da pergunta.

### Sobre o Xtech

Até aonde entendi *Xtech* é um ecommerce pronto (seria mais um CMS) então biblioteca não faz muito sentido, provavelmente o que você procura é uma **funcionalidades** do sistema deles, a não ser que você seja capaz de controlar algum script ou API deles, mas isto você não especificou na pergunta, então se existe tal API ou biblioteca, você deve informar como usou ela.

Se você se refere ao bootstrap, então você deve informar que problema exatamente ocorre com ele, eu tentei ler duas vezes depois de fechar e mesmo assim não consigo entender aonde esta o seu problema.

### Entendendo o fechamento

Nunca presuma que é por algo a não ser que alguém tenha comentado o motivo, o que você tem que fazer é seguir o que esta escrito no rodapé da pergunta fechara, no caso da sua pergunta:

> **marcada como pendente** como *não está clara o suficiente* por jbueno, rray, bigown, Guilherme Nascimento, Randrade 17 horas atrás
>
> Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página Como perguntar para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.
>   Conheça as regras na central de ajuda e edite a pergunta para que fique adequada.

*Não está clara o suficiente* é porque **você** não conseguiu expor o problema e não apenas a falta de código e as vezes você dizer bootstrap não funciona ou postar uma foto não deixa claro aonde pode ser a sua falha, temos que conseguir reproduzir o problema, então sim é totalmente necessário um código ou exemplos de como você incluiu a biblioteca jquery, bootstrap.js e bootstrap.css (presumindo que você esteja falando do bootstrap).

Uma questão do meta parecida com a sua:

- [como lidar com uma pergunta que depende de um conhecimento além da programação?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4266/3635)

Aonde o autor achou que as perguntas citadas foram fechadas por se tratarem da linguagem [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), mas na verdade os problemas eram com falta de clareza ou incapacidade de reproduzir o problema.